# What does displayModeButtonItem actually do?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, back-button, master-detail

I am learning the basic controls and template with Xcode 6.3 and iOS SDK 8.3. After I created a **Master-Detail** view template, I tried to change the backbutton's title on the **detailview's navigationbar**.

I first changed navigationbar's title on the masterview in storyboard, and it seems working on iPhone6 simulator: first the masterview is loaded, whose title has been changed; then after the detailview is pushed the backbutton's title is also changed.

But when it comes to iPad air simulator, the strange thing happens: the title of detailview's backbutton remains "Master"(iPad is in portrait direction), no matter what method I used.

After I used several methods found in stackoverflow, I dig into the code and found two places which may controls the behavior of the backbutton in detailview:

1. (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
   in **AppDelegate.m**:

   ```
   navigationController.topViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
   ```
2. (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender in **MasterViewController.m**:

   ```
   controller.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem;
   ```

It seems the splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem acts like a backbutton in a collapsed scene(iPhone), also acts like triggering PrimaryOverlay mode in Portrait direction in iPad, and even disappears in landscape direction in iPad.

I'm very curious about how the displayModeButtonItem controls its behavior(like when to appear, what text it shows), so I can make custom changes to it under different circumstances(I have tried to modify the text property or replace it with another button, all fails).

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's own documentation :

> A system bar button item whose action will change the displayMode
>   property depending on the result of
>   targetDisplayModeForActionInSplitViewController:. When inserted into
>   the navigation bar of the secondary view controller it will change its
>   appearance to match its target display mode. When the target
>   displayMode is PrimaryHidden, this will appear as a fullscreen button,
>   for AllVisible or PrimaryOverlay it will appear as a Back button, and
>   when it won't cause any action it will become hidden.

```
- (UIBarButtonItem *)displayModeButtonItem NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0);
```

The behaviour is handled automatically for you by Apple, it will also present an "expand" button on iPhone 6 plus in landscape mode